# Error en VB6 con SOAP y servicio web HTTPS

Tags: soap, vb6, https

Por favor, su apoyo en este asunto. Tengo un app cliente en VB6, Soap Toolkit 3.0 y un servicio web .Net 4.0 implementado con HTTPS.

```
Private oWS As SoapClient30 
Set oWS = New SoapClient30 
oWS.MSSoapInit2 "https://serv01/ws_my/wsservice.asmx?wsdl", "", "wsservice.asmx", "wsservicesoap", "http://tempuri.org"
```

Este método `MSSoapInit2` recibe: WSDL, WSML, ServiceName, Port, Namespace.

Lanza el siguiente error:

> WSDLReader: XML Parser failed at linenumber 0, lineposition 0, reason
>   is:  System error: -2146697191 HRESULT=0x1: Incorrect function.
>   -WSDLReader: Loading of the WSDL file falied HRESULT=0x80070057: The parameter is incorrect.
>   -Client: One of the parameters supplied is invalid. HRESULT=0x80070057: The parameter is incorrect.

Gracias por su atención y apoyo.

Comment: El puerto esta correcto? Por favor mira [ask] para que te podamos ayudar mejor

Comment: Todos los parámetros son correctos. El app funciona bien con HTTP. Sin embargo, al cambiar la configuración a HTTPS, falla.